# ckeditor5 angular Link is not opening in the new tab addTargetToExternalLinks is not working

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am using angular 13 and ckeditor5 40.2 like below:

<ckeditor [editor]="editorService.Editor" [config]="{ link: { addTargetToExternalLinks: true },language: 'de' }" [(ngModel)]="data" (change)="handleEditorChange($event)">
Here in the [config] I provided link & locale, it is working fine for locale but link is not opening in the new tab during rendering, please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: This is issue with my internal sanitization tool, closing the bug.

Answer (score 0):

This is issue with my internal sanitization tool, closing the bug.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a bug tracker or something. It's a Question&Answer website. You can't close a question like that, you can delete it if you want. Also, if it's useful, you can [edit] your post to change how you fixed it